# Control block diagram with sampling output

Tags: control, control-system, sampling

[image]

I'm learning control theory and in my book it shows an example of this block diagram, the output [image: c(z)=G2(Z)G1R(Z)/(1+G1G2H(z))]

I'm quite confused  because the last step I got is 
[image]
 , I can't get the same answer after transfer this answer to Z domain.

Please help me 
[image]

Comment: Show your steps.

Comment: @Chu I just uploaded it, not sure if the work I had done is correct

Comment: Just take G1HC(z)G2(z) to the left side, and C(z) is a common factor.

Comment: ＠Chu Can I do that? I thought G1HC(z) is a single function. The book says the Z transfer Z[G1(s)G2(s)]=G1G2(z) but I couldn't find the formula on conversion table I found... I just wondering what's the meaning of G1 standalone, is it just a constant?

Comment: Let the forward path (\$G_1\: sampler\: G_2\$) be \$G_3(s)\$, then obtain the loop equation in s, then do the z-transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let \$\small G_3(s)=\left[ G_1(s)\rightarrow sampler \rightarrow G_2(s)\right]\$, and \$\small C(s)=\$ output signal of \$\small G_2(s)\$; then the loop equation is:
$$\small C(s)= \frac{R(s)\:G_3(s)}{1+H(s)\:G_3(s)}$$

Taking z-transforms:

\$\small R(s)G_3(s)\rightarrow RG_3(z)\rightarrow RG_1(z)\:G_2(z)\$ (noting that \$\small RG_1\$ and \$\small G_2\$ may be separated due to the intervening sampler);

\$\small H(s)G_3(s)\rightarrow HG_1G_2(z)\$ (noting that \$\small HG_1\$ and \$\small G_2\$ cannot be separated since \$\small HG_1\$ is not a signal)

Hence: $$\small C(z)= \frac{RG_1(z)\:G_2(z)}{1+HG_1G_2(z)}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "HG1" is not a signal?

Comment: H and G1 are both transfer functions, and you can't sample a transfer function. RG1 is a signal, since it's the response of G1 to the input, R, so it can be sampled to produce RG1*

Comment: Oh, I think I got it, the equation I derived seems wrong.